# Copy & Paste selected rows to another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy the data of rows in Worksheet1 that is not null on a specific row column and paste it to worksheet2. My problem is when I paste it to worksheet2, it will only paste to one row.

```
' 1. Find first blank row in the destination range based on data in column A

  lDestLastRow = wsDest.Range("Table1").Columns(1).Find(What:="", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Row


' Check the rows in Column N if null in worksheet1
  For i = 20 To 28

    If wsCopy.Cells(i, 15).Value <> "" Then
        'MsgBox wsCopy.Range("A" & i).Value
        wsCopy.Range("A" & i).Copy
        wsDest.Range("A" & lDestLastRow).Columns(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

   End If

Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lDestLastRow` only calculated once before enter the `For...Next` loop. Thus, it will not change. You can either calculated it in every loop, or add 1 to the stored value for each loop.